# ListView item onClick color stays the same for a second after I return to the activity, how to refresh it?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-linearlayout, listviewitem

So I am using the following so I can change the on click color of my listview item. However, I am annoyed at what is happening when I return to my activity after the click - the color stays the same as when I clicked on it for about a second and then it refreshes to the normal background. Also, if I hold the listview item and slide my finger away, the listview item stays as it is continuously clicked on and does not return until I tap on another listview item. How can I only change the background color of the listview item on tap only and not have it stay the same after I switch back to the same activity? Here is my code. Thanks!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repeatable"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CategoriesActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categoriesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@color/White"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_view_item_background_on_click">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Layout for individual news entries in a list -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/list_view_item_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="12.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="3.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="8.0dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingLeft="2sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search_holo_light">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/imgUrl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>



<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="@color/Teal" />
    <solid android:color="@color/Teal" />
</shape>
```

Comment: can you post your adapter code, it sounds like your views are being recycled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here seems to be a good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html) But you want to use `state drawables` to change the color in different states such as `focused, pressed, enabled, disabled`

[StateListDrawable Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Doing it this way, the color will change when you press on it but when you return the state won't be pressed so it will be the default color, which I believe is what you want.